# merge multiple actions into a single one in effects

Tags: rxjs, observable, ngrx

I have the following list of action and I want to merge them so that I return a list of action and execute them one by one.

I tried

```
    map(drones => {
      const actions = [];
      drones.forEach((drone) => actions.push(new featureActions.OpenUsedDroneUpdateChannelRequest({ droneId: drone.id, projectId : environment.projectId })));
      actions.push(new featureActions.GetUsedDronesSuccess({drones}));
      return forkJoin(actions);
    }),
```

I also tried

```
    map(drones => {
      const actions = [];
      drones.forEach((drone) => actions.push(new featureActions.OpenUsedDroneUpdateChannelRequest({ droneId: drone.id, projectId : environment.projectId })));
      actions.push(new featureActions.GetUsedDronesSuccess({drones}));
      return merge(actions);
    }),
```

booth doesn't works

> ERROR Error: Effect "UsedDronesEffect.getUsedDrones$" dispatched an
>   invalid action: {"_isScalar":false}
>
> ```
> core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: Actions must have a type property
>     at
> ```

How can I merge them ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dispatch multiple actions from effects: difference between different rxjs operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940197/dispatch-multiple-actions-from-effects-difference-between-different-rxjs-operat)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to return an array of actions with on of the following operators `mergeMap`, switchMap`and`concatMap`. Also does it have to return an array of actions, why not dispatch the actions one by one?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following example or try using `mergeMap()` to combine your new actions

```js
@Effect() drones = this.dronesEffect.pipe(
   ...,
   switchMap((res: drones[]) => drones.map(x => new featureActions.OpenUsedDroneUpdateChannelRequest({ droneId: drone.id, projectId : environment.projectId })))
   )
);
```

Check out this [Article](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/dispatching-multiple-actions-from-ngrx-effects-c1447ceb6b22)